# Обновление данных раз в N секунд

Tags: java, rxjava, rxjava2

Есть локальный источник данных:

```java
Observable<Data> getData();
```

Есть запрос, чтобы их обновить:

```java
Completable updateData();
```

Хочу чтобы данные начинали обновляться раз в N секунд, если на них подписаны.
Что сделал:

```java
Observable<Object> timer = Observable.interval(N, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .flatMap(tick -> updateData().toObservalbe()).retry(N * 1000);

Observable<Data> getUpdatableData(){
   return Observable.merge(timer, getData())
         .filter(o -> o instanceof Data)
         .map(o -> (Data) o);
}
```

Подскажите как избавиться от пары косяков:

1. Если подписаться на getUpdatableData() несколько раз, то раз в 10 секунд будет происходить не одно обновление, а по количеству подписок.
2. Надо избавиться от приведения типов после merge

Задача довольно типичная, но не могу найти хороших примеров.

Comment: Ну самое первое что приходит в голову это сделать проверку:"Подписан ли этот подписчик уже"?", либо же если подписчиков много и чтоб их не дублировать хранить какой-то сет подписчиков и следить за их удалением/добавлением.

Comment: По поводу приведения мне кажется вам тут нужно заменить merge, на цепочку с flatmap. Observable.interval(...). flatmap {getUpdatebleData()}